# 'apt-get update' fails when using proxy

Tags: apt, ppa, proxy, launchpad

Using  apt-get update I am getting

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages              
404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch
http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/jupiter/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages
404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
ones used instead.
```

The machine is behind proxy and proxy is configures correctly and the error is not coming for  other packages fetched from the internet. It is more common with ppas. Never got a problem with other sources.

had the problem with:

```
deb http://_ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu precise main
deb [arch=amd64] http:__ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/jupiter/ubuntu precise main
```

also tried using Acquire::http {No-Cache=True;};
and treid cleaning the cache of list sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*

Nothing worked out. The url that fails opens perfectly in browser or using wget.

This problem only happens when using proxy.

Comment: Can you open those URLs successfully in a browser or with `wget` from behind the proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of Ubuntu and version you are using. Check your Ubuntu version using the command :

```
lsb_release -a
```

**Ubuntu** has proxy switcher, where you can choose -- apply systemwide -- like button. Then apt should work behind proxy with no problem.

**Xubuntu** and other non-gnome clones don’t have any proxy switcher, so there is necessary to update `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxies95` file.

If you have a username and password with the proxy then, open `apt.conf`:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

You'll see

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://proxyIP:port/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://proxyIP:port/";
```

change it to

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://username:password@proxyIP:port/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://username:password@proxyIP:port/";
```